# Got "does not name a type when using static variable in *.c file"

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I am compiling frmts/gtiff/libtiff/tif_dirinfo.c file from GDAL using android ndk and g++.
The tiffFieldArray is defined as a static variable at beginning.

```
static TIFFFieldArray tiffFieldArray;
```

Then I use it in the same file:

```
tiffFieldArray = { tfiatImage, 0, TIFFArrayCount(tiffFields), tiffFields };
```

But got error:

```
../../frmts/gtiff/libtiff/tif_dirinfo.c:264:1: error: 'tiffFieldArray' does not name a type
```

Why?

In tif_dir.h, the struct definition:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

...

struct _TIFFFieldArray {
        TIFFFieldArrayType type;    /* array type, will be used to determine if IFD is image and such */
        uint32 allocated_size;      /* 0 if array is constant, other if modified by future definition extension support */
        uint32 count;               /* number of elements in fields array */
        TIFFField* fields;          /* actual field info */
};
...

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

Comment: in the same file or in the same scope?

Comment: which one is the 264th line? Have you included the necessary file or tiffFieldArray?

Comment: @Zaibis in the same file

Comment: @LaszloPapp  tiffFieldArray = { tfiatImage, 0, TIFFArrayCount(tiffFields), tiffFields }; is at 26th line

Comment: @DeanChen: I meant TIFFFieldArray. Where is that declared?

Comment: @LaszloPapp 
It is defined in tiffio.h file 
typedef struct _TIFFFieldArray TIFFFieldArray;

Comment: @LaszloPapp 

struct _TIFFFieldArray {
        TIFFFieldArrayType type;    /* array type, will be used to determine if IFD is image and such */
        uint32 allocated_size;      /* 0 if array is constant, other if modified by future definition extension support */
        uint32 count;               /* number of elements in fields array */
        TIFFField* fields;          /* actual field info */
};

Comment: @DeanChen: hmm, comment formatting break it. Please put it into the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a variable from an initializer list:

```
tiffFieldArray = { tfiatImage, 0, TIFFArrayCount(tiffFields), tiffFields };
```

this syntax works only in variable definitions, not assignments. Substitute that line with:

```
    tiffFieldArray[0] =  tfiatImage;
    tiffFieldArray[1] =  0;
    tiffFieldArray[2] =  TIFFArrayCount(tiffFields);
    tiffFieldArray[3] =  tiffFields;
```

**EDIT** (after mor info was added in the question)

`tiffFieldArray` has a misleading name, since it is a structure, not an array. Anyway the previous solution I posted cannot work in this case. Try writing:

```
    tiffFieldArray.type =  tfiatImage;
    tiffFieldArray.allocated_size =  0;
    tiffFieldArray.count =  TIFFArrayCount(tiffFields);
    tiffFieldArray.fields =  tiffFields;
```

Comment: Still got error. I tried this before asking this question.
../../frmts/gtiff/libtiff/tif_dirinfo.c:264:1: error: 'tiffFieldArray' does not name a type
../../frmts/gtiff/libtiff/tif_dirinfo.c:265:1: error: 'tiffFieldArray' does not name a type
../../frmts/gtiff/libtiff/tif_dirinfo.c:266:1: error: 'tiffFieldArray' does not name a type
../../frmts/gtiff/libtiff/tif_dirinfo.c:267:1: error: 'tiffFieldArray' does not name a type